# Meteor Reactive Tables nested data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have reactive tables working with meteor.  I am trying to implement a simple master detail solution.  Basically When a row is selected in table 1 the details come up in table 2. When I try and access nested data it shows up in my table as [object: Object]

I am using this package: https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#nested-objects-and-arrays

my schema looks like:

```
ActivityLogs = new Meteor.Collection ('activityLogs');

ActivityLogsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    "aid" : {
      type: String,
      label: "aid"
    },
    "logs": {
      type: Array
    },
    "logs.$": {
      type: Object
    },
    "logs.$.stdout": {
      type: String
    }

});

ActivityLogs.attachSchema( ActivityLogsSchema );

ActivityLogs.attachSchema( ActivityLogsSchema );
```

in my html:

```
{{> reactiveTable collection=activityStdout settings=settings1}}
```

My activityStdout helper:

```
activityStdout: function() {
  var aid = Session.get('selectedAid');
  if (aid != null) {
    // return ActivityLogs.find({"aid": aid}, {"logs.stdout": 1});
    return ActivityLogs.find({"aid": aid});

}
```

The collection data looks like:

```
db.activityLogs.find({aid:"7aba0960-b31f-11e7-af97-c56765123d72"}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e5d080702ec0000df939b6"),
    "aid" : "7aba0960-b31f-11e7-af97-c56765123d72",
    "logs" : [
        {
            "stdout" : "performed substitutions on asset dir config-dir/app/config-dir/config-dir-file-2.json"
        },
        {
            "stdout" : "performed substitutions on asset dir config-dir/app/config-dir/config-dir-file-1.json"
        },
        {
            "stdout" : "performed substitutions on asset file undefined"
        },
        {
            "stdout" : "created package package::/sandboxeter./pipe5/app/dev2::pipe5-app-config-Sprint-5.7.4"
        }
    ]
}
```

in my settinggs1 helper:

```
settings1: function () {
return {
    // collection: activityStdout,
    rowsPerPage: 25,
    showNavigation: 'auto',
    showFilter: false,
    fields: [
      // {key: 'aid'           , label: 'AID' },
      {key: 'logs'      , label: 'Logs'},
      {key: 'stdout'       , label: 'output'}
    ]
};
}
```

I would like my reactive table to show any key in the logs array.  I have been playing with the key above.  I have tried:  logs.stdout, logs.$.stdout and several other variants with the key.

In the table I get:

[image]

The below code works to get the right data but it doent use the reactive table:

```
          <table id="mytable2" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
             <tr>
                <td>{{aid}}</td>
             </tr>
             {{#each activitiesLogList}}
             {{#each logs}}
             <tr>  {{stdout}} </tr>
             {{/each}}
             {{/each}}
          </table>
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much time with google this is apparently isnt supported with this Meteor Package.

I found this:  https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table/issues/376

The Author Package says:

> The only thing that works right now is a specific array index, like
>   notes.0.remindersActive. There's no way to filter for something
>   anywhere in the array. Do those work in mongo selectors?